# Is it possible to treat a format specifier as a variable?

Tags: c, time, format-specifiers

I would like for this function to be able to return data from the given `time_t` argument according to the `specifier` argument.

If specifier is `'d'`, it should return the Day of the month (01-31);
If specifier is `'W'`, it should return the Week of the year (00-53).

```
int get_number_atr_from_time(time_t raw_time, char specifier) {
    struct tm *info = localtime(&raw_time);

    char buffer[3];
    strftime(buffer, 3, "%specifier", info);

    return atoi(buffer);
}
```

Can this somehow be done?

Comment: The title and tag mentions `printf`, but there is no `printf` anywhere here. But to answer the question in the title: Yes, there's nothing special about the string passed as a format string to printf. Though you should never let user-defined data leak its way into there, because it's possible to cause stack corruption using maliciously defined format strings.

Comment: If you want you can construct your own format string at run time, but you can't create your own specifier. This could be an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) though.

Comment: Yes it can be done.  But wouldn't it be as simple to have two functions?

Comment: If you want to return the time field as an *integer*, it seems rather roundabout to use `strftime` to turn it into a string, then use `atoi` to turn it back into an integer!  Is that really what you want to do?  (Yes, this does let the caller pass in, as `specifier`, any format specifier character that `strftime` would accept, without further interpretation of the specifier.)

Comment: It might be simpler to just have `get_number_atr_from_time` return `info->tm_mday+1` or `info->tm_yday` directly, without calling `strftime`.  (But then again, it might be simpler for the caller to do this themselves, without having a `get_number_atr_from_time` function at all.)

Comment: But, yes, you can do what you're asking.  It will look something like `char specString[3]; construct specString using specifier; strftime(buffer, 3, specString, info);`.  All you have to do is figure out how to construct a proper string in the `specString` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many (if not *most*) of the standard C functions that take a "format" argument, such as `printf` and – as in your code – [`strftime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime), take that argument as a `const char*`. However, that does **not** mean it has to be a **string literal**.

Any `char` array that you have declared and written-to yourself (i.e. *not* `const`) can still be passed as a `const char*` argument. So, you can write the required format specifier to a pre-declared `format` array and then pass that to the `strftime` function.

In the following code, I show how you can do this to get the current day-of-month and week-of-year, passing `'d'` and `'W'`, respectively, to your function, which then writes that (together with the required `%` prefix) to the format string used for the `strftime` call.

```c
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int get_number_atr_from_time(time_t raw_time, char specifier)
{
    struct tm* info = localtime(&raw_time);
    char buffer[3];
    char format[3] = { '%', specifier, 0 }; // Initialize as "%X", where X is
    strftime(buffer, 3, format, info);      // "specifier" - and add null char
    return atoi(buffer);
}

int main(void)
{
    time_t tNow = time(NULL);
    int dy = get_number_atr_from_time(tNow, 'd');
    int wk = get_number_atr_from_time(tNow, 'W');
    printf("D = %d, W = %d\n", dy, wk);
    return 0;
}
```

Output as of the date of posting:

```
D = 13, W = 45
```

---

Note that there will be a number of more efficient ways to retrieve the day and week values from a `time_t` or `struct tm` value, but the above code shows how to solve your *specific* problem.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use *compound literal*:

```
strftime(buffer, 3, (char []){'%', specifier, 0}, info);
```